# Keep getting undefined method error in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

I've got a controller action 'show' which i'm trying to test. The controller looks like this:

```
def show
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
  @my_entry = current_user.entries.where(contest_id: params[:contest_id]).sort_by { |entry| -entry.total_points}
  @points_per_player = @my_entry[0].points_per_player
  @total_points = @my_entry[0].total_points
  @opponents = @contest.entries.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).sort_by { |entry| -entry.total_points}
  @opponent_squad = Squad.find(@opponents[0].squad_id)
  @opponent_points = @opponents[0].points_per_player
end
```

and the spec for the show action looks like this:

```
describe 'GET /show' do
   let!(:user) { create(:user) }
   let!(:squad_1) { create(:squad) }
   let!(:squad_2) { create(:squad) }
   let!(:contest) { create(:contest) }
   let!(:my_entry) { create(:entry, user_id: user.id, contest_id: contest.id) } 
   let!(:opponents) { [:squad_1, :squad_2] } 
   let!(:opponent_squad) { create(:squad) }

 before :each do
   sign_in user
   controller.instance_variable_set(:@opponent_squad, :squad )
   get :show, contest_id: contest.id
 end

 it "renders the show template" do
   (expect (response.status)).to eql(200)
   (expect (assigns(:opponents))).to eql([:squad_1, :squad_2])
   (expect (assigns(:opponent_squad))).to eql(:squad)
 end
end
```

Rspec keeps throwing the error "undefined method `squad_id' for nil:NilClass", which i think refers to the second last line in the show action, i.e:

```
@opponent_squad = Squad.find(@opponents[0].squad_id)
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? (Note I'm extremely new to Rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line

```
 @opponents = @contest.entries.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).sort_by { |entry| -entry.total_points}
```

You are looking for all entries where the user_id is not the current user. But in your spec the entry you create

```
  let!(:my_entry) { create(:entry, user_id: user.id, contest_id: contest.id) }
```

sets the user_id to the current user so that @opponents collection won't end up with any results.

You then look for @opponents to have a value

```
 @opponent_squad = Squad.find(@opponents[0].squad_id)
```

And get an exception.

I'd suggest two things. First update the spec to make sure an instance of that Entry class has been created with a different user_id so that @opponents gets a result and second wrap the last two lines in your controller with a check on @opponents.any? so that you don't end up breaking things if there are no opponents.

Answer (score 0):

In last third line you are using current_user.id:

```
 @opponents = @contest.entries.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).sort_by { |entry| -entry.total_points}
```

But in your spec you define entry with curre_user

```
let!(:my_entry) { create(:entry, user_id: user.id, contest_id: contest.id) }
```

And here you are searching all entries without current_user.id:

```
@opponents = @contest.entries.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).sort_by { |entry| -entry.total_points}
```

For your spec you should create other user and create for him an entry.